# Use python SSL to download google.com.au page

Tags: python, ssl

The following code is capable of retrieving the source code for the main page of a secure website, such as www.stgeorge.com.au

```
import socket, ssl
context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_OPTIONAL
context.check_hostname = True
context.load_default_certs()
host = 'www.stgeorge.com.au'
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=host) 
ssl_sock.connect((host, 443)) 
ssl_sock.send('GET https://' + host + ' HTTP/1.0\n\n')

while True:
    data = ssl_sock.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    print data
ssl_sock.close()
```

However, if I replace www.stgeorge.com.au with www.google.com.au, pyton reports error "SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED"

What do I need to do to get the source code from google.com.au?

Regards,
Nick

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: There is this great python network library called [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) which almost everyone is using.

Comment: I installed requests, put together a simple code based on the explanations, but when I try to download the source code, it raises errors about UnicodeEncodeError. I will have to look at how to use this library. It would have been nice if they provided some functional sample code.

Answer (score 0):

After using the requests library, as suggested by skyline75489, the code looks like this:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.google.com.au')
f = open('test.txt', 'w')
f.write((r.text).encode('utf8'))
f.close()
print((r.text).encode('utf8'))
```

Thanks for help

Comment: You could use `urllib.request` as well (`urllib2` on Python 2). In fact, `requests` is a better interface but it's an external module to install, while `urllib` is part of the standard library.